# VBA: Type mismatch error trying to pass string in item method

Tags: excel, vba, variables, parameter-passing, type-mismatch

I'm trying to write a vba code that gets from an excel range the names of my chart and serie that are located on my powerpoint slide to give me the position of the corresponding datalabel. For some reason I have a Type mismatch error. I think it occurs when I pass my string variables as arguments of the 'item' method, because when I replace them by their actual string value the code works fine.

```
Sub datalabelposition()
 
Dim pp As Object
Dim sl As Object
Dim chtName As Variant
Dim serName As Variant
Dim rnge As Range
 
Set pp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
Set sl = pp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set rnge = Worksheets("Macro").Range("J10:P29")
 
chtName = rnge(1, 1).Value
chtName = CStr(chtName)
serName = rnge(1, 2).Value
serName = CStr(serName)
 
Debug.Print chtName
Debug.Print serName
Debug.Print sl.Shapes.Item(chtName).Chart.SeriesCollection.Item(serName).Points(1).DataLabel.top
 
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: `CreateObject` creates a new instance of PPT, with no open presentations (unless you have some auto-opening ones).  So it's not clear what `ActivePresentation` would be in this case.

Comment: The target presentation is already opened in the background. I wrote this line just so that I could modify it using VBA on excel. Is there a better way to access an already opened PowerPoint presentation from the VBA code in excel ?

Comment: Typically you'd use `GetObject()` if you want to work with an already-open presentation.